# Spring Security @PreAuthorize with application itself as user

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've got a spring application set up with spring security. I've got my service methods annotated with @PreAuthorize(...). So everyone from the web needs some specific rights to access those methods, which is fine.

But now I've got a new use case. There's a @Scheduled method running to do some checks and send messages. Currently only people with ROLE_USER are allowed to send messages. But now also the application itself has to send those messages.

How should I manage to have some kind of invisible user (= the application), which is logged in all the time and has specific rights? Or maybe "all rights" would be nice as well, so it just ignores all those security annotations.
Or maybe I don't need a "user" at all?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: The main 2 questions are:

1. Should I create a real user for the application? Means: An entry in the user table of the database? How did you solve this? Maybe you do simply use the user account of the admin user (which is a real person)?
2. If I now have this "system" user. What's the best way to "use" it? For example I'd use @Autowired User systemUser to access this user wherever I need it. (Of course there's some point in the application config where I create a bean with this specific user).

EDIT2: Some more thoughts:

I think in the future I want to send messages from different subsystems of the application. So it's no choice to use the admin user, because I need a few different users with different names.

Answer (score 3):

I was faced with similar problem and the solution I implemented was an internal and an "external" service implementation. The external one has the internal one autowired in. Any application-internal component, like your scheduled job, would have the **internal** service wired in. Any Web-exposed components would have the **secured "external"** service wired in, which would have the `@PreAuthorize` etc. annotations in place, but otherwise would act just as a delegate to the internal service.

I also log, before passing message onto the internal service, the principal of the authentication object which was used for authorization. You know you'll have one available in the SecurityContext, so pick it out and just make a note in your logs of someone external invoking internal services. I do the below (your principal could be non-username, but still, wanted to share):

```
final String currentUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that all the answers you provided are fairly common solutions, so it depends very much on your requirements. The app I'm working on has some intense audit requirements so we have a user set up for the application itself to use when it needs to invoke services through a scheduler. This allows us to log against a given principle. Perhaps you should clarify your requirements?

Comment: It's just as simple as: The scheduler checks if there are some new entries in Table A for User X. If there are new entries, the system will generate a message for that User X, and this message contains some text and links to those new entries. Nothing special. ... I just need answer to two questions (I'll append those to the question in a minute)

Comment: The enterprise in which I work uses a central directory accessed by ldap. We have had a system user entered into this system. We pick up the credentials from a property file that is provided to the system by the system administrators in each environment. The property file is used to lookup the credentials whenever they are needed. We do not cache the principal, because it must be authenticated before each call, in our case.

Comment: It's not a great idea to be hard coding the credentials into your app, where they can be reverse engineered. Also, credentials tend to be different in each environment -- dev, integration, qa, pre-prod, and prod.